# How to add text to JText area without deleting the previous text it has? java

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a `JText area` in my program contain a text, and I want to add more text to it, when a `button` is pressed but without deleting the `text` that it already has on it. for example

```
JTextArea Text = new JTextArea("including; ");
```

When a `button` is pressed, I have to `add another text` but without `deleting` the one it has already, like so;

```
Text.setText("including button1");
```

and when another button is pressed it should look like this

```
Text.setText("including; button1, button2");
```

What is the most effective way of doing this?

Comment: Piece of advise, don't start your variables with captial letters, it mixes them up with java keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the append feature, like this

```
Text.append("button1,");
```

place this in the button / s and just write the name of the button